# Informix SQL SELECT multi-row result - how to present in one row?

Tags: sql, informix

Following request:

```
select s.site_name as site, NVL(ct.calltypename,"<No queue assigned>") as queue,
  AVG(TO_NUMBER(cd.datavalue)) as average, count(distinct cr.callid) as count
from callrecord cr 
left join calldata cd on cd.callid=cr.callid and cd.sitekey=cr.arrivalsite and cr.requeuecount=cd.requeuecount-1 
left join calltypes ct on cr.arrivalsite=ct.sitekey and cr.calltypekey=ct.calltypekey
left join sites s on cr.arrivalsite=s.sitekey
where cd.datakey="key1"
group by site, queue
```

produce following result:

```
  site  queue                   average    count
  MSK     <No queue assigned>   3.00       4
  MSK     Sales                 2.00       1                
  MSK     Service               3.63       32
```

There may be up to 6 rows in the result.
**Task is to reformat the output for the application that use SQL to retrieve data.
This application can send only one SQL command and can process only one row.**
So SQL result should look like:

```
  site1   queue1   average1   count1   site2   queue2   average2  count2 ...
  MSK     Sales    2.00       1        MSK     Service  3.63      32
```

It is also important that each queue should always appear in the same column; if there is no data, column should be empty, null or zero. I have found some examples for MS SQL, but they do not work in Informix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
with t as (
      < your query here >
     )
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then site end) as site_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then queue end) as queue_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then average end) as average_1,
       . . . 
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then site end) as site_6,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then queue end) as queue_6,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then average end) as average_6,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by site order by queue) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: I couldn't make your example to work, but idea with max(case...) was very helpful. Finally I achieved the desired result with the similar code.